# Java Swing and Excel

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to write the data from table format to to Excel sheet,during this date  is shown as "#######" in excel.But while i increasing the cell size the date is visible correctly.So i want to increase the width size of the excel file from the code itself.Is anyone can help me ?The code is below`

JButton btnExport = new JButton("Export To Excel");

```
    btnExport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {

            btnExport.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);

            btnExport.addActionListener(new AksyonListener());
        }

        public void toExcel(JTable table1, File file) {
            try {

                System.out.println("Success");
                FileWriter excel = new FileWriter(file);

                  // DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                // table.setModel(model);
                  //  model.insertRow(table.getRowCount(), new Object[]{0});
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    excel.write(table.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
                    System.out.println(table.getColumnName(i));
                }
                /*  int d,f;
                 System.out.println("d: "+table.getRowCount());
                 System.out.println("f: "+table.getColumnCount());*/

                excel.write("\n");

                for (int i = 1; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {

                        excel.write(table.getValueAt(i, j) + "\t");
                        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(i, j));
                    }
                    excel.write("\n");
                }

                excel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        class AksyonListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (e.getSource() == btnExport) {
                    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                    int option = fc.showSaveDialog(TableSortFilter.this);
                    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
                        String path = fc.getSelectedFile().getParentFile().getPath();

                        int len = filename.length();
                        String ext = "";
                        String file = "";

                        if (len > 4) {
                            ext = filename.substring(len - 4, len);
                        }

                        if (ext.equals(".xls")) {
                            file = path + "\\" + filename;
                        } else {
                            file = path + "\\" + filename + ".xls";
                        }
                        toExcel(table, new File(file));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use apache poi to export and create excel 
https://poi.apache.org/